# Hiding nested vertical menu until mouse over (Nav menu)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having some trouble using jQuery to hide my vertical menu. I just learned jQuery, so I am fairly new to using it. I can't get jQuery to modify anything (change color for example, using any action.. `mouseenter()`, `click()` etc)

Help is much appreciated.

**EDIT:** I am getting errors in JSLint.. trying to use jQuery in brackets editor. Not sure what to do :/ First error is on line 1 using $ before defined.. any help would be awesome

This code is simply trying to change the green "link1, link2, link3" text from green to purple when mousing over "Program"

***also, is there a way to easily reduce the size of my ul li items? The area that I can currently click is larger than the text. I tried modifying my display: property, but that messes up the layout of my list.. *******

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#headerMenu > li').mouseenter(function() {
       ('#headerMenu ul li a').Color('purple'); 
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link type = "text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    <title>Home Page</title> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <ul id="headerMenu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">DROP</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#'>LINK 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>LINK 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>LINK 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">LOGIN</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="mainPhoto">   fffffff
            <div> change color</div>
        </div>
        <div id="mainScrollUp">    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

css code

```
.header {
    background-color: skyblue;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

/* Main centered menu on top */

    #headerMenu {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

#headerMenu > li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

#headerMenu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 2rem;
    }

#headerMenu li a:hover {
    color: lightgray;
}

/* Sub Menu for Link One */

#headerMenu ul {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    color: red;
    padding-left: 0;
    position:absolute;
}

#headerMenu ul li a{
    color:green;
}


#mainPhoto {
    height: 650px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: bisque;
    color:palevioletred;

}

#mainScrollUp {
    z-index: 1;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: aqua;
    clear: both;
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> error is on line 1 using $ before defined

You forgot to define jQuery. Try and add the following line to your header tag in your HTML file.

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Put it before your own script.js please, that way jQuery is defined before calling it in your script.

Understanding your vertical submenu goal, I came up with this:
https://jsfiddle.net/wsj59p20/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! if you wouldnt mind + voting my question, trying to get rep. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I don't think [this](http://jsfiddle.net/b0o0o4j3/) is what you want but it fixes some of your syntax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#headerMenu > li').mouseenter(function() {
       $(this).find('ul>li>a').css('color', 'purple'); 
    });
});
```

Also, your "using $ before defined" error seems to because you aren't loading jQuery at all in your sample code.